# Error while creating S3 bucket using localstack

Tags: python, docker, amazon-s3, localstack

I have cloned localstack repo and exposed it with docker-compose up and I got the port 4566, as you can see the logs :

```
localstack_main | [2021-02-26 06:30:24 +0000] [22] [INFO] Running on https://0.0.0.0:4566 (CTRL + C to quit)
localstack_main | 2021-02-26T06:30:24:INFO:hypercorn.error: Running on https://0.0.0.0:4566 (CTRL + C to quit)
localstack_main | Starting mock API Gateway service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock CloudFormation service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock CloudWatch service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
localstack_main | Starting mock DynamoDB service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock DynamoDB Streams service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock EC2 service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock ES service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock Firehose service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock IAM service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock STS service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock Kinesis service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock KMS service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock Lambda service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock CloudWatch Logs service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock Redshift service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock Route53 service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock S3 service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock Secrets Manager service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock SES service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock SNS service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock SQS service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock SSM service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock Cloudwatch Events service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock StepFunctions service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Starting mock SWF service on http port 4566 ...
localstack_main | Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
localstack_main | Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
localstack_main | Ready.
localstack_main | 2021-02-26T06:30:43:INFO:localstack.utils.analytics.profiler: Execution of "start_api_services" took 19441.94793701172ms
```

Now I am trying to create the s3 bucket as follows:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 mb s3://mca-temp
```

In result I am getting :

```
make_bucket failed: s3://mca-temp Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:4566/mca-temp"
```